# How to get the coordinates and dimension of a div using Java

Tags: java, coordinate, html-parser

there

I am working on a project which would translate the html code of a web into a specific JS library using JAVA, so that the div blocks can have different dynamic behaviors.

To translate the html div into a JS object, I have to know the coordinates of it as well as the width and length.

I turned into several JAVA html parser library: http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers

But none of them have this functionality except Cobra http://lobobrowser.org/cobra/java-html-parser.jsp . It has a rendering engine which could provide the coordinates and dimension of a div. But this library turns out to be really buggy. I cannot even run through its test which comes with the library.

Does anyone know how to handle this problem? I would really appreciate it if you could help!

Thanks in advance!
Phil

Comment: You might be able to do something with Selenium and its Firefox or Chrome drivers, maybe, but not sure. Or, I suppose, using JNI and a rendering engine that supports JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You could try some component of [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/), which emulates a browser. Honestly though, I think you need to think about your question more carefully. [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) can do the 'different dynamic behaviours' thing you talk about via modification of the HTML DOM (Document Object Model) with Javascript, and if you need anything in the HTML document, inspection of the DOM via Javascript should be your first port of call. Java should not be required anywhere (unless you're using it server-side for page and input processing with JSP or some similar tech). Any responses to client input can be triggered server-side and sent to Javascript on the client-side, which triggers JQuery actions that modify the DOM.